# Set query type dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq, nhibernate

I need your help. I wanna implement a database request with different types depending on the users role.

My current query looks like this:

```
var myVar = session
            .Query<TypeA>()
            .Where(xyz)
            .ToList();
```

Now I wanna do it like this:

```
if(UserIsAdmin)
     Type T = TypeA;
else
     Type T = TypeB;

var myVar= session
           .Query<T>()
           .Where(xyz)
           .ToList();
```

Notice `TypeA` an `TypeB` should be dynamically changed in `.Query<T>`.

Is there any good way to do this? Do you need more information?

Thanks in advance :-)

**EDIT:**

The scenario looks as follows:

I have to get different models from the database depending on the users roles. Lets say the user is Admin he can see `firstname, lastname, address`, if not he can only see `firstname, lastname`.

I thought to create two different models with these attributes and change the type in the query dynamically.

Comment: This is very bad programing practice, please tell us what is the scenario and we will think of a better approach. A DB layer method will always give you a very explicit `DbEntity` as a result.

Comment: Get three columns always and don't show address column for other roles.

Comment: @omriman12 Any ideas?

Comment: @trinadh exactly what I'm trying to do?!

Comment: Then you don't need Query<T>. You can add a property "IsVisible" for each  attribute. Whenever other roles need this data for them IsVisible attribute will be false for Address and Isvisible is always true for other attributes. Now use this property to hide and show depends on the role. I guess i am making sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to understand first the consept of seperating layers.

So first of all you will have a `DB layer`, which in your case(though i don't know you db schema), but it should look something like:

```
public class UsersDbServices 
{
    public UserDbEntity GetUserById(int userId)
    {
        UserDbEntity user = null
        using (context..)
        {
            user = context.Users.Where(u=> u.Id = userId).FirstOfDefault();
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

You will call this service from you `Logic` layer, note that you can use the same method for both `normal` user and `administrator`!

Now for the clinet side I would return a DTO(data transfer object) which will be the same for both cases!:

```
public class UserDTO
{
    public int UserId { get;set;}
    public string FirstName { get;set;}
    public string LastName { get;set;}
    public string Address { get;set;}       
}
```

Now the last part is the controller, here you will get the data from the `DBLayer`(you can go through another layer of logic, but lets say its not a must), and what you will do now in the controller you can poppulate the `DTO`(and again you can do this all in the logic layer as well) in this way:

```
public class UsersController
{
    UsersDbServices m_UsersDbServices = new UsersDbServices ();

    [HttpGet]
    public UserDTO GetUserById(userId)
    {
        UserDTO retVal = null;

        UserDbEntity userDbEntity  = m_UsersDbServices.GetUserById(userId);
        if(userDbEntity == null){
            throw...
        }

        retVal = new UserDTO()
        {
            FirstName  = userDbEntity.FirstName;
            ...
        };

        if(!UserIsAdmin) <- kept it as a bool here
        {   
            retVal.Address  = null;
        }

        return retVal; <- convert to json
    }
}
```

Another approach is to use another DTO like `AdminUserDTO` and `RegularUserDTO`